# Restarting own qt application

Tags: c++, qt, reload

I trying this code for reload my app

```
#include <QThread>
#include <QProcess>

...

// restart:
qApp->quit();
QThread::msleep(5000);
QProcess::startDetached(qApp->arguments()[0], qApp->arguments());
```

on my computer it is working. But on another not, because the app closing some sec and it will take differ times. What better alternative can i use?

Comment: Welcome at SO! I am not sure if I understand the problem correctly... Does the app not restart sometimes or does it just take too long time? BTW: I am wondering why `quit()` is called **before** the app is restarted (I would have expected this as last line of code).

Comment: My app must be closed. So quit() for it. When app closing that destroy another plugins and it take a few time, so i can't reload immediately. For resolve this problem i use msleep(), but it fixed time and on another computer app closing more time. So i want to wait for close all plugins. Thanks for greeting))

Comment: And quit() standing before cause i have block of double run app.

Comment: I have built a tool that has the same feature but without sleeping the thread and it works in linux and win without problem...

Comment: See https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_make_an_Application_restartable

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Please show us your solution here (if it is open source or a code snippet)

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ. I solved the problem by combining solutions. My example plus [link](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_make_an_Application_restartable). In main.cpp:
`code` 

QString appForRestart = qApp->arguments()[0];

int result = application->exec();

if (result == 12345) {
    QProcess::startDetached(appForRestart);
}

return result;

and in the slot(function) where called restart i use:
`code`
qApp->exit(12345);